# adb command fail to execute if path contain spaces

Tags: android, shell, command-line, terminal, adb

I am trying to delete the file using adb command. But the file contain spaces. So adb command throws an error after reading half of the file name till space. Is there a way to overcome this issue. I am executing following adb command

When I execute

```
adb shell rm /sdcard/samsung_Nexus S_converter.xml
```

Error message: rm failed for /sdcard/samsung_Nexus, No such file or directory

How ever when I execute:

```
adb shell rm /sdcard/samsung_Nexus_S_converter.xml
```

File deletion is successful

I searched for solution for this, if there is any workaround. How ever I couldnt find any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using command line, you need to know that spaces must be escaped by using (backslash before the special character like "space"), so, in your case this should work too:

> adb shell rm /sdcard/samsung_Nexus\ S_converter.xml

Hope it helps!

Regards!

Comment: Awesome. I missed that. It worked for me now. Thanks a lot! I thought this is adb specific.

Comment: If the answer was helpful don't forget to mark it as correct, so other people take time to answer your questions...

Comment: I am trying to accept the answer. However I can only accept answer only after 15 min after asking question. Give me 5 min I will do that. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 7):

By me it wasn't enough to escape spaces with backslashes:

```
$ adb shell ls /storage/sdcard1/audio/Die\ Toten\ Hosen/
/storage/sdcard1/audio/Die: No such file or directory
Toten: No such file or directory
Hosen/: No such file or directory
```

For some reason I also had to surround the path with `'` (single quotation):

```
$ adb shell ls '/storage/sdcard1/audio/Die\ Toten\ Hosen/'                                                                                                                       
03 - Boxed Set                                                                                                                                                                                                     
04 - Compilations                                                                                                                                                                                                  
05 - Live Albums
```

While surrounding without escaping didn't work:

```
$ adb shell ls '/storage/sdcard1/audio/Die Toten Hosen'                                                                                                                       
/storage/sdcard1/audio/Die: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                                              
Toten: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                                                                   
Hosen: No such file or directory
```

Comment: +1, but why is it tho. what comes to mind is that the quote only exists on the working machine and the escapes on the client side

Comment: ok I think I'm right ```adb shell ls "'/storage/sdcard1/audio/Die Toten Hosen'"``` also works

Comment: @Mab Now it seems logical to me that I had to surround the path as it wasn't a path on the local file system. Escaping would be enough on local file system, but the path was passed to `adb` command as argument. If it's not surrounded `adb` considers it as 3 arguments because of spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried escaping the space

`adb shell rm /sdcard/samsung_Nexus\ S_converter.xml`

Comment: Awesome. I missed that. It worked for me now. Thanks a lot! I thought this is adb specific.