# Is it possible to delete file using appium?

Tags: python, android, appium

I am testing my application and as part of the current scenario, I have been creating several files inside my `android`. I want to delete these files after I finish my tests.

So, appium has this `pull file`, `push file` and `pull folder`, but I cannot see any documentation for `delete file`.

In the windows file explorer, my device is visible under `This PC\P00A\Internal shared storage` and inside this path I can see all my folders but I cannot reach this path somehow using `python`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try using adb:

```
 adb shell rm <file>
```

Comment: What path should i set for my file ? only file name ? what should be the root path ? /sdcard ?

Comment: i try adb shell rm /sdcard/folder/t1.csv but it says No such file or directory

Comment: try giving the absolute exact path to the file which you want to delete.

Comment: What to do if my folder name is with space ?

Comment: u can use backslashes i.e '\' before special characters like space

Comment: eg : samsung_Nexus S_converter.xml can be replaced by samsung_Nexus\S_converter.xml   , u can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683077/adb-command-fail-to-execute-if-path-contain-spaces?rq=1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197494/discussion-between-shreyash-sharma-and-falukky).

Answer (score 0):

The command for removing files from android is this:

```
adb shell rm </sdcard/test.txt>
```

You might want to try that command from cmd on terminal till u make it work because files' paths on Android are pretty tricky.

You will be able to find all of the options of the (rm) command in this link:
http://adbshell.com/commands/adb-shell-rm

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mobile:shell command](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/android-shell/#mobile-shell) to execute whatever you want on the mobile device:

```
result = driver.execute_script('mobile: shell', {
    'command': 'rm',
    'args': ['/sdcard/file.txt'],
    'includeStderr': True,
    'timeout': 5000
})
print(result['stdout'])
```

It might be easier to use [Run Command (adb)](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Run%20Command%20(adb)) shorthand available via [Appium SeeTest Extensions](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/SeeTest+-+Appium+Extension):

```
seetest.run(("adb shell rm /sdcard/file.txt");
```