# BroadcastReceiver receive extra with ADB --es not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, adb

I registered a broadcast receiver in the `MainActivity.onCreate` method with the following statements:

```
...
// in onCreate()
val filter = IntentFilter("com.example.my_receiver.TEST_FILTER")
registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter)
...
```

with the following receiver

```
private val myReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

when I executed the add command

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.example.my_receiver.TEST_FILTER
```

the `onReceive` method will be executed. But when I try to add some extra data with the following

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.example.my_receiver.TEST_FILTER --es test_data "My testdata"
```

nothing will be executed. How can I send extra data with `adb` and receive it in the `BroadcastReceiver` implementation? The `compileSdk` and `targetSdk` is 31.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you try without whitespace in the first place, or just escape the whitespace, seen also here:

[adb command fail to execute if path contain spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683077/adb-command-fail-to-execute-if-path-contain-spaces)

Comment: The command `adb shell am broadcast -a com.example.my_receiver.TEST_FILTER --es test_data "MyTestdata"` works